# My fork()ing runsim.c program is running too slow

Tags: c, command-line, parallel-processing, fork

I have an assignment for class that just doesn't want to work right. I'm supposed to execute by taking in an argument from command line with a link to a data file like this: " ./runsim 3 < testing.data  "
The program is supposed to read lines from that file, fork() out child processes, and use the lines from the data document to execute another program called testsim. Testsim and the data document were provided by our teacher, and all the students I've talked to say theirs runs fast. I've referenced their projects and my code is very similar, yet myine still runs slow. I work on it through SSH so I don't think it's my hardware. Any ideas as to what is slowing this down would be deeply appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t childpid=0;
    int pr_limit, pr_count=0, status;
    char s[MAX_BUF], program[MAX_BUF], num1[MAX_BUF], num2[MAX_BUF];

    if(argc!=2){ /* check for valid number of command-line arguments */
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s (int) < filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    pr_limit=atoi(argv[1]);

    while(fgets(s, 100, stdin)){
        /* checks pr_limit and waits for a child to finish if reached  */
        if(pr_count==pr_limit){
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            pr_count--;
            printf("Child Exit Code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }

        /* reads in strings for commands  */
        sscanf(s, "%s %s %s", program, num1, num2);
        /* this if loop creates forks from the parent */
        if((childpid=fork())<=0){
            /* this if loop catches fork failures */
            if(childpid<0){
                perror("Child Failed To Fork");
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }

        pr_count++;

        /* executes commands from file in child  */
     /* if(childpid==0){
            printf("%s %s %s\n", program, num1, num2);
            execl(program, program, num1, num2, NULL);
        } */

        /* checks to see if any child has finished */
        if(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)!=0){
            pr_count--;
        }
    }

    /* executes commands from file in child  */
    if(childpid==0){
        execl(program, program, num1, num2, NULL);
    }

    while(1){
        childpid=waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
        if(childpid==-1){
            break;
        }
        pr_count--;
        printf("Child Exit Code: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you run a profiler on your code?  If not, this is a good time to do that.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with profilers yet. I'm still pretty green. I want to understand why it's not working, but since this has already been graded and I still have finals this week, I'll have to wait to learn to use a profiler on it until next week. I was just hoping there were problems people who are more experienced than me might see and be able to point out.

Comment: if this statement: `execl(program, program, num1, num2, NULL);` ever returns, then it failed..  But do not want the parent process to be executed by the child process.  So follow that statement with: `perror( execl failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: Since the posted code is expecting a `int` parameter, the code should be validating that parameter to be >0

Comment: regarding: `pr_limit=atoi(argv[1]);`   The function: `atoi()` is easy to use, but does not give any indication when an error occurs.  Suggest using something like: `strtol()`

Comment: the exit status of some child should be checked after this call: `waitpid(-1, &status, 0);` the same as in the final loop of the program.  Similar considerations exist for this code block: `if(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG)!=0){
            pr_count--;`

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for this statement: `sscanf(s, "%s %s %s", program, num1, num2);` any return value other than 3 indicates an error  But, `errno` is not updated, so cannot use `perror()`.  Suggest using: `fprintf( stderr, ...);` When using either '%s' or '%[...]` input format specifiers, always include a MAX FIELD WIDTH modifier that is one less that the length of the input field.  Because those input/format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  Otherwise, the input field can be overflowed, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(s, 100, stdin)){`  the scope of this statement needs to include the code block: `if(childpid==0){
        execl(program, program, num1, num2, NULL);
    }`  otherwise only one call to `execl()` will ever be executed and since the `fgets()` has already read past the end of the input file, any values being passed to `execl()` are either 'stale' or garbage.

Comment: please post a few lines of the input file and the exact value you are using for the command line parameter